# cant configure dataSource and delegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, git, delegates, datasource

So i upgraded Xcode and the GitHub project code to swift 3.0 (my project is in Obj C and some of the pods i use from GitHub are in Swift). I got a bunch of errors and now i am stuck on these ones. For some reason my dataSource and delegate for the floatingActionButton ([git here](https://github.com/yoavlt/LiquidFloatingActionButton)) now doesn't work. I tried to set the `dataSource` and `delegate` programmatically and on storyboard but it didn't work.

Errors:

> Property 'dataSource' not found on object of type 'LiquidFloatingActionButton *'
>
> Property 'delegate' not found on object of type 'LiquidFloatingActionButton *'

I believe if i figure out the `dataSource` and `delegate` issue then it'll fix the colour error below.

Screenshot:
[image]

.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ProductContentViewController.h"

#import "LiquidFloatingActionButton-swift.h"

@interface SetScreenViewController : UIViewController



<UIPageViewControllerDataSource, LiquidFloatingActionButtonDelegate, LiquidFloatingActionButtonDataSource>

...

@end
```

.m:

```
        #import "LiquidFloatingActionButton-Swift.h"

LiquidFloatingActionButton *floatingActionButton;
NSMutableArray *liquidCells;
bool *closeFloatingButtons;


NSString *videoToWatchURL;


- (void)addLiquidButton{

    //Grabs the coordinates bottom right of the screen    
    float X_Co = self.view.frame.size.width - 50;
    float Y_Co = self.view.frame.size.height - 50;

    //i subtract 10 so the button will be placed a little bit out
    X_Co = X_Co - 10;
    Y_Co = Y_Co - 10;


    //I create each cell and set the image for each button
    liquidCells = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [liquidCells addObject:[[LiquidFloatingCell alloc]initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"]]];
    [liquidCells addObject:[[LiquidFloatingCell alloc]initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"]]];
    [liquidCells addObject:[[LiquidFloatingCell alloc]initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"]]];
    [liquidCells addObject:[[LiquidFloatingCell alloc]initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"]]];
    [liquidCells addObject:[[LiquidFloatingCell alloc]initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"]]];
    [liquidCells addObject:[[LiquidFloatingCell alloc]initWithIcon:[UIImage imageNamed:@".png"]]];



    //Sets the floating button at the loaction provided
    floatingActionButton = [[LiquidFloatingActionButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(X_Co, Y_Co, 50, 50)];
    floatingActionButton.dataSource = self;//Error here
    floatingActionButton.delegate = self;//and here.

    //I set the color of the floating button
    floatingActionButton.color = [self colorWithHexString:@"01b8eb"];




    //Enables the user interaction fuction to true so itll open or close
    floatingActionButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    //Adds the flaoting button to the view
    [self.view addSubview:floatingActionButton];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfCells:(LiquidFloatingActionButton     *)liquidFloatingActionButton{
    return liquidCells.count;
}

-(LiquidFloatingCell *)cellForIndex:(NSInteger)index{
    return [liquidCells objectAtIndex:index];
}
```

PodFile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Whats New' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Whats New

  target 'Whats NewTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'Whats NewUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

pod 'CRToast', '~> 0.0.7'

pod "LiquidFloatingActionButton"

pod 'DGActivityIndicatorView'

pod 'M13ProgressSuite'

pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.8'

pod 'FSCalendar'

use_frameworks!






post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end









end
```

> **UPDATE BELOW**

I ended up using [this](https://github.com/Friend-LGA/LGPlusButtonsView) project because the original GitHub was not being fixed, thanks for all the help and if someone does figure this out please let everyone here know!

Comment: That's Objective-C code, not Swift 3 code.

Comment: @rmaddy a-ha! The component has been upgraded to Swift 3.0, not the OP's code.

Comment: @rmaddy my project is in objective c, the GitHub being used is in Swift. Sorry, i didn't mention this.

Comment: Could you show the content of Podfile?

Comment: Yes, just updated the question

Comment: I guess your cocoapod pod is not updated for swift 3.x use, trying using header bridges

Comment: I'm not trying to use my Obj-C code in .swift code, I'm trying to get my Obj-C project to use the .swift GitHub project.

Answer (score 3):

If the swift `@protocols` are not define with `@objc` then you can't access them in objective-c,

e.g

```
@objc public protocol xxxxxxxxxxxDelegate {
   func functionOne()
   func functionSecond()
}
```

Comment: So is this the single GitHub project problem? because I'm using other swift GitHub projects in my Obj C project perfectly fine

Comment: Yes may be, you need check the file of that project where particular @protocols are declared.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that your Objective-C code does not know the „`open var`“s `dataSource` and `delegate` of the `LiquidFloatingButton` Swift code.
To make them known, a Obj-c header file is required that exposes these Swift infos to your Obj-C code. This is described in detail in the Apple docs „[Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)“, in your case particularly in the section „*Importing External Frameworks*“.  It says:
*You can import a framework into any Objective-C .m file within a different target using the following syntax:*

```
@import FrameworkName;
```

Comment: Sorry i should have added more details in my code. I did indeed add the framework code into my project. check my updated question so see.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add a bridging header to your project? To use Swift code in an Objective-C project you need a bridging header. Here's what to do,

1.Create a new .swift file

2.A popup window will appear and ask **"Would You like to configure an Objective-C bridging Header"**. Choose **Yes**.

3.Click on your Xcode Project file ,Click on **Build Settings**

4.Find the Search bar and search for **Defines Module**.

5.Change the value to **Yes**.

6.In App delegate, add the following : **#import "YourProjectName-swift.h"**

Whenever you want to use your Swift file you must add the following line :

```
#Import "YourProjectName-swift.h"
```

Comment: did everything in this answer and it still has the same error

Comment: Also I'm using a GitHub project, not my own swift files/delegates.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using `LiquidFloatingActionButton` in a **Swift 3** project. Note that the project on the git uses `SnapKit` for **Swift 2.3**, which I also had to deal with, but this is out of scope here. The solution for me was not to use `@objc public protocol`, but to change protocol declaration as follows:

```
public protocol LiquidFloatingActionButtonDataSource {
    func numberOfCells(_ liquidFloatingActionButton: LiquidFloatingActionButton) -> Int
    func cellForIndex(_ index: Int) -> LiquidFloatingCell
}
```

And also:

```
public protocol LiquidFloatingActionButtonDelegate {
    // selected method
    func liquidFloatingActionButton(_ liquidFloatingActionButton: LiquidFloatingActionButton, didSelectItemAtIndex index: Int) 
}
```

Only than I could successfully use delegation in my **Swift 3** project.

Comment: My project uses Objective-C, not Swift 3.0.